# Server Sent Events not working in android by using domain name URL

Tags: android, cordova, webview, cordova-plugins, openhab

I am using this URL from Ajax “https://username:password@home.myopenhab.org/rest/events?topics=smarthome/" to get SSE(Server Sent Events) in client side application from server using Cordova.

- Its working fine on IOS but its not working on android
- (I am using android 7.0, latest chrome version and also enabled the webview implementation in developer options).
- for same URL if I give IP like "http://192.168.0.1/rest/events?topics=smarthome/” its working fine on both IOS and android.

Note:Both URL(“https://username:password@home.myopenhab.org/rest/events?topics=smarthome/" AND "http://192.168.0.1/rest/events?topics=smarthome/”),
 working fine with the "cordova-crosswalk-plugin" but i dont want to use crosswalk plugin beacuse asking for download some dependency application from google play.

```
var eventSource = new EventSource(" +“url”+ /rest/events?topics=smarthome/*");   

eventSource.addEventListener(‘message’, function (eventPayload){

//not entering here.

}
```

Comment: Do you get any error messages during the build or run time ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32148646/in-cordova-on-android-app-requests-with-https-fail-but-same-request-using-http-s), I'll say it here:

Reason is your URL use `https`

You can try remove `onReceivedSslError` method in `\cordova\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\ CordovaWebViewClient.java`

then add `handler.proceed()`

Comment: hello , thank you for your reply.. their is no file called CordovaWebViewClient.java in mentioned path. I found SystemWebViewClient.java in \cordova\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova\engine  path i have changed the  handler.proceed() in else part but its not working...

Comment: I am using cordova 8.1.2